# How to reference project in a Roslyn analyzer without nuget?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing a Roslyn analyzer/code generator.
It has to deserialize a Json.The classes used for this are also used by another project so create said Json.
The idea was to put all these classes into a shared assembly.

The normal linking of the projects does not work as it gives a `FileNotFoundException`.
While I could package the shared project as a nuget this would be a total hassle during initial development.

So is there a way to include a project in an analyzer without nuget (or duplicating the code)?